# Why doesn't this AJAX code work in IE8?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Someone help me solve this query. My ajax code which seems to be not working with IE8 browser. It has got no issues with any other browser.  The functionality is to bring dynamic values of "Snowboards Sold" and "Cash for the Slopes:" after every time "show Me the Money button" is clicked.

The code from random values are `enter code here`produced using php. I believe there is nothing I need to change in that code as this is a browser issue.

The ajax code is given below:

```
 <head>
  <title>Boards 'R' Us</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boards.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="text-utils.js"> </script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var request = null;
//Declaring object for browsers
   function createRequest() {
     try {
       request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } catch (trymicrosoft) {
       try {
         request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
       } catch (othermicrosoft) {
         try {
           request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
         } catch (failed) {
           request = null;
         }
       }
     }

     if (request == null)
       alert("Error creating request object!");
   }

//function called on clicking show me the money button clicked
   function getBoardsSold() {
     createRequest();
     var url = "getUpdatedBoardSales-ajax.php";
     request.open("GET", url, true);
     request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
     request.send(null);
  }

  function updatePage() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      var newTotal = request.responseText;
      var boardsSoldEl = document.getElementById("boards-sold");
      var cashEl = document.getElementById("cash");
      replaceText(boardsSoldEl, newTotal);

      /* Figure out how much cash Katie has made */
      var priceEl = document.getElementById("price");
      var price = getText(priceEl);
      var costEl = document.getElementById("cost");
      var cost = getText(costEl);
      var cashPerBoard = price - cost;
      var cash = cashPerBoard * newTotal;

      /* Update the cash for the slopes on the form */
      cash = Math.round(cash * 100) / 100;
      replaceText(cashEl, cash);
    }
  }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>Boards 'R' Us :: Custom Boards Report</h1>
  <div id="boards">
   <table>
    <tr><th>Snowboards Sold</th>
     <td><span id="boards-sold">1012</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th>What I Sell 'em For</th>
     <td>$<span id="price">249.95</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th>What it Costs Me</th>
     <td>$<span id="cost">84.22</span></td></tr>
   </table>
   <h2>Cash for the Slopes: 
    $<span id="cash">167718.76</span></h2>
   <form method="GET">
    <input value="Show Me the Money" type="button"
           onClick="getBoardsSold();" />
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: how about start using a javascript library like jquery which makes things easier for you for dom traversing, ajax handling etc... ?www.jquery.com

Comment: At one point in my programming career, I used to hand code everything. I've reached the point where there are too many browsers out there. JQuery is the way to go...

Answer (score 1):

Might i recommend the very standard and widely used JQUERY?

http://jquery.com/

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

And then for a little very simple magic, replace the portion about creating an AJAX and the call by this:

```
$.get('getUpdatedBoardSales-ajax.php', updatePage);
```

Keep your updatePage function as it is already and you're set!